# How to change Slick Slider default arrow using data attributes?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, slick.js

**How to change default arrow using data attributes?**

```
<div class="has-slick-slider" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 1, "arrows": true, "prevArrow": "<button type="button" class="slick-prev">Prev</button>"}'>
```

`slidesToShow`, `arrows`, and others attributes work smoothly. but when I tried to change arrow content it does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add html for your custom button and include selector of this element as `prevArrow` value like this:

```
<div class="has-slick-slider" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 1, "arrows": true, "prevArrow": "#custom-prev-arrow"}'>
    ...
</div>
<button id="custom-prev-arrow">...</button>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: #Thanks, it's Work.

Comment: Hello Irina, When I used same id or class name in the different slider on one page it's doesn't work. Have any solution for this?

Comment: @RajuAhammad, hi.
Please avoid using of same ID for one page. If you use one element (I mean button) for two sliders, it will allow this button to change a slide for two sliders simultaneously. 
You can create as more buttons as needed, give them same class for styling (if they should look similar to each other) and different IDs. In that way you can easily use these IDs as a config for your sliders. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/irinpotapova/3c4qg8bL/14/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS escape sequence: `\u0022`:

```
<div class="has-slick-slider" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 1, "arrows": true, "prevArrow": "<button type=\u0022button\u0022 class=\u0022slick-prev\u0022>Prev</button>"}'>
</div>
<button id="custom-prev-arrow">...</button>
```